# Extract specific value from XML array (where FieldName = x)

Tags: sql, arrays, xml, oracle, oracle18c

*Oracle 18c:*

**Test #1:**

The following query works as expected. It selects values from XML (the XML is a clob column via a view).

Query:

```
select
    cast(substr(extractvalue(a.column_value,'/Subtype/SubtypeCode'),1,255) as number(9,0)) as subtype_code,
    substr(extractvalue(a.column_value,'/Subtype/SubtypeName'),1,255) as subtype_name,
    substr(extractvalue(a.column_value,'/Subtype/FieldInfos/SubtypeFieldInfo/FieldName'),1,255) as field_name,
    substr(extractvalue(a.column_value,'/Subtype/FieldInfos/SubtypeFieldInfo/DomainName'),1,255) as domain_name
from
    sde.gdb_items_vw
cross join
    xmlsequence(xmltype(definition).extract('/DETableInfo/Subtypes/Subtype')) a     --https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4499629/at-what-version-did-the-table-keyword-for-table-collection-expressions-become-optional
where
    name = 'INFRASTR.EVENTS_ONLY_1_ARRAY_VALUE'
```

```
SUBTYPE_CODE   SUBTYPE_DESCRIPTION               FIELD_NAME  DOMAIN_NAME
------------   --------------------------------  ----------  --------------
           0   ACTIVE TRANSPORTATION             ACTIVITY    ACTIVITY_ATN_1
           1   GEODETIC CONTROL SURVEY MONUMENT  ACTIVITY    ACTIVITY_GCSM
           2   MUNICIPAL STRUCTURES (BRIDGES)    ACTIVITY    ACTIVITY_MS
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DETableInfo xmlns:typens="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.7" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="typens:DETableInfo">
   <CatalogPath>\INFRASTR.BC_EVENTS</CatalogPath>
   <Name>INFRASTR.BC_EVENTS</Name>
   <ChildrenExpanded>false</ChildrenExpanded>
   <DatasetType>esriDTTable</DatasetType>
   <DSID>60337</DSID>
   <Versioned>false</Versioned>
   <CanVersion>true</CanVersion>
   <ConfigurationKeyword />
   <RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion>10.0</RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion>
   <HasOID>true</HasOID>
   <OIDFieldName>OBJECTID</OIDFieldName>
   <GPFieldInfoExs xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfGPFieldInfoEx">
      <GPFieldInfoEx xsi:type="typens:GPFieldInfoEx">
         <Name>OBJECTID</Name>
         <AliasName>OBJECTID</AliasName>
         <ModelName>OBJECTID</ModelName>
         <FieldType>esriFieldTypeOID</FieldType>
         <IsNullable>false</IsNullable>
         <DomainFixed>true</DomainFixed>
         <Required>true</Required>
         <Editable>false</Editable>
      </GPFieldInfoEx>
      <GPFieldInfoEx xsi:type="typens:GPFieldInfoEx">
         <Name>ASSET_CLASS</Name>
         <AliasName>ASSET_CLASS</AliasName>
         <ModelName>ASSET_CLASS</ModelName>
         <FieldType>esriFieldTypeSmallInteger</FieldType>
         <DefaultValueNumeric>2</DefaultValueNumeric>
         <IsNullable>true</IsNullable>
      </GPFieldInfoEx>
      <GPFieldInfoEx xsi:type="typens:GPFieldInfoEx">
         <Name>ACTIVITY</Name>
         <AliasName>ACTIVITY</AliasName>
         <ModelName>ACTIVITY</ModelName>
         <FieldType>esriFieldTypeString</FieldType>
         <IsNullable>true</IsNullable>
      </GPFieldInfoEx>
   </GPFieldInfoExs>
   <CLSID>{7A566981-C114-11D2-8A28-006097AFF44E}</CLSID>
   <EXTCLSID />
   <RelationshipClassNames xsi:type="typens:Names" />
   <AliasName />
   <ModelName />
   <HasGlobalID>false</HasGlobalID>
   <GlobalIDFieldName />
   <RasterFieldName />
   <ExtensionProperties xsi:type="typens:PropertySet">
      <PropertyArray xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty" />
   </ExtensionProperties>
   <SubtypeFieldName>ASSET_CLASS</SubtypeFieldName>
   <DefaultSubtypeCode>2</DefaultSubtypeCode>
   <Subtypes xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfSubtype">
      <Subtype xsi:type="typens:Subtype">
         <SubtypeName>ACTIVE TRANSPORTATION</SubtypeName>
         <SubtypeCode>0</SubtypeCode>
         <FieldInfos xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfSubtypeFieldInfo">
            <SubtypeFieldInfo xsi:type="typens:SubtypeFieldInfo">
               <FieldName>ACTIVITY</FieldName>
               <DomainName>ACTIVITY_ATN_1</DomainName>
            </SubtypeFieldInfo>
         </FieldInfos>
      </Subtype>
      <Subtype xsi:type="typens:Subtype">
         <SubtypeName>GEODETIC CONTROL SURVEY MONUMENT</SubtypeName>
         <SubtypeCode>1</SubtypeCode>
         <FieldInfos xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfSubtypeFieldInfo">
            <SubtypeFieldInfo xsi:type="typens:SubtypeFieldInfo">
               <FieldName>ACTIVITY</FieldName>
               <DomainName>ACTIVITY_GCSM</DomainName>
            </SubtypeFieldInfo>
         </FieldInfos>
      </Subtype>
      <Subtype xsi:type="typens:Subtype">
         <SubtypeName>MUNICIPAL STRUCTURES (BRIDGES)</SubtypeName>
         <SubtypeCode>2</SubtypeCode>
         <FieldInfos xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfSubtypeFieldInfo">
            <SubtypeFieldInfo xsi:type="typens:SubtypeFieldInfo">
               <FieldName>ACTIVITY</FieldName>
               <DomainName>ACTIVITY_MS</DomainName>
            </SubtypeFieldInfo>
         </FieldInfos>
      </Subtype>
   </Subtypes>
   <ControllerMemberships xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfControllerMembership" />
   <EditorTrackingEnabled>false</EditorTrackingEnabled>
   <CreatorFieldName />
   <CreatedAtFieldName />
   <EditorFieldName />
   <EditedAtFieldName />
   <IsTimeInUTC>false</IsTimeInUTC>
   <ChangeTracked>false</ChangeTracked>
   <FieldFilteringEnabled>false</FieldFilteringEnabled>
   <FilteredFieldNames xsi:type="typens:Names" />
</DETableInfo>
```

[Screenshot from the application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdTNE.png)

---

**Test #2:**

*Regarding the 3rd and 4th columns in the query:*

In the first test, the `<FieldInfos...>` array only had a single value: `ACTIVITY`.

However, in this next test, the `<FieldInfos...>` array has multiple values: `ACTIVITY` and `STRATEGY`. So when I run the same query, it will fail because it can't return multiple values for a single column.

Query:

```
select
    cast(substr(extractvalue(a.column_value,'/Subtype/SubtypeCode'),1,255) as number(9,0)) as subtype_code,
    substr(extractvalue(a.column_value,'/Subtype/SubtypeName'),1,255) as subtype_name,
    substr(extractvalue(a.column_value,'/Subtype/FieldInfos/SubtypeFieldInfo/FieldName'),1,255) as field_name,
    substr(extractvalue(a.column_value,'/Subtype/FieldInfos/SubtypeFieldInfo/DomainName'),1,255) as domain_name
from
    sde.gdb_items_vw
cross join
    xmlsequence(xmltype(definition).extract('/DETableInfo/Subtypes/Subtype')) a
where
    name = 'INFRASTR.EVENTS_MULTIPLE_ARRAY_VALUES'
```

Error:

```
ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node
19025. 00000 -  "EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node"
*Cause:    Given XPath points to more than one node.
*Action:   Rewrite the query so that exactly one node is returned.
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DETableInfo xmlns:typens="http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.7" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="typens:DETableInfo">
   <CatalogPath>\INFRASTR.BC_EVENTS</CatalogPath>
   <Name>INFRASTR.BC_EVENTS</Name>
   <ChildrenExpanded>false</ChildrenExpanded>
   <DatasetType>esriDTTable</DatasetType>
   <DSID>60337</DSID>
   <Versioned>false</Versioned>
   <CanVersion>true</CanVersion>
   <ConfigurationKeyword />
   <RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion>10.0</RequiredGeodatabaseClientVersion>
   <HasOID>true</HasOID>
   <OIDFieldName>OBJECTID</OIDFieldName>
   <GPFieldInfoExs xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfGPFieldInfoEx">
      <GPFieldInfoEx xsi:type="typens:GPFieldInfoEx">
         <Name>OBJECTID</Name>
         <AliasName>OBJECTID</AliasName>
         <ModelName>OBJECTID</ModelName>
         <FieldType>esriFieldTypeOID</FieldType>
         <IsNullable>false</IsNullable>
         <DomainFixed>true</DomainFixed>
         <Required>true</Required>
         <Editable>false</Editable>
      </GPFieldInfoEx>
      <GPFieldInfoEx xsi:type="typens:GPFieldInfoEx">
         <Name>ASSET_CLASS</Name>
         <AliasName>ASSET_CLASS</AliasName>
         <ModelName>ASSET_CLASS</ModelName>
         <FieldType>esriFieldTypeSmallInteger</FieldType>
         <DefaultValueNumeric>2</DefaultValueNumeric>
         <IsNullable>true</IsNullable>
      </GPFieldInfoEx>
      <GPFieldInfoEx xsi:type="typens:GPFieldInfoEx">
         <Name>ACTIVITY</Name>
         <AliasName>ACTIVITY</AliasName>
         <ModelName>ACTIVITY</ModelName>
         <FieldType>esriFieldTypeString</FieldType>
         <IsNullable>true</IsNullable>
      </GPFieldInfoEx>
      <GPFieldInfoEx xsi:type="typens:GPFieldInfoEx">
         <Name>STRATEGY</Name>
         <AliasName>TEST_TEXT_FIELD</AliasName>
         <ModelName>STRATEGY</ModelName>
         <FieldType>esriFieldTypeString</FieldType>
         <IsNullable>true</IsNullable>
      </GPFieldInfoEx>
   </GPFieldInfoExs>
   <CLSID>{7A566981-C114-11D2-8A28-006097AFF44E}</CLSID>
   <EXTCLSID />
   <RelationshipClassNames xsi:type="typens:Names" />
   <AliasName />
   <ModelName />
   <HasGlobalID>false</HasGlobalID>
   <GlobalIDFieldName />
   <RasterFieldName />
   <ExtensionProperties xsi:type="typens:PropertySet">
      <PropertyArray xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty" />
   </ExtensionProperties>
   <SubtypeFieldName>ASSET_CLASS</SubtypeFieldName>
   <DefaultSubtypeCode>2</DefaultSubtypeCode>
   <Subtypes xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfSubtype">
      <Subtype xsi:type="typens:Subtype">
         <SubtypeName>ACTIVE TRANSPORTATION</SubtypeName>
         <SubtypeCode>0</SubtypeCode>
         <FieldInfos xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfSubtypeFieldInfo">
            <SubtypeFieldInfo xsi:type="typens:SubtypeFieldInfo">
               <FieldName>ACTIVITY</FieldName>
               <DomainName>ACTIVITY_ATN_1</DomainName>
            </SubtypeFieldInfo>
            <SubtypeFieldInfo xsi:type="typens:SubtypeFieldInfo">
               <FieldName>STRATEGY</FieldName>
               <DomainName>STRATEGY</DomainName>
            </SubtypeFieldInfo>
         </FieldInfos>
      </Subtype>
      <Subtype xsi:type="typens:Subtype">
         <SubtypeName>GEODETIC CONTROL SURVEY MONUMENT</SubtypeName>
         <SubtypeCode>1</SubtypeCode>
         <FieldInfos xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfSubtypeFieldInfo">
            <SubtypeFieldInfo xsi:type="typens:SubtypeFieldInfo">
               <FieldName>ACTIVITY</FieldName>
               <DomainName>ACTIVITY_GCSM</DomainName>
            </SubtypeFieldInfo>
            <SubtypeFieldInfo xsi:type="typens:SubtypeFieldInfo">
               <FieldName>STRATEGY</FieldName>
               <DomainName>STRATEGY</DomainName>
            </SubtypeFieldInfo>
         </FieldInfos>
      </Subtype>
      <Subtype xsi:type="typens:Subtype">
         <SubtypeName>MUNICIPAL STRUCTURES (BRIDGES)</SubtypeName>
         <SubtypeCode>2</SubtypeCode>
         <FieldInfos xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfSubtypeFieldInfo">
            <SubtypeFieldInfo xsi:type="typens:SubtypeFieldInfo">
               <FieldName>ACTIVITY</FieldName>
               <DomainName>ACTIVITY_MS</DomainName>
            </SubtypeFieldInfo>
            <SubtypeFieldInfo xsi:type="typens:SubtypeFieldInfo">
               <FieldName>STRATEGY</FieldName>
               <DomainName>STRATEGY</DomainName>
            </SubtypeFieldInfo>
         </FieldInfos>
      </Subtype>
   </Subtypes>
   <ControllerMemberships xsi:type="typens:ArrayOfControllerMembership" />
   <EditorTrackingEnabled>false</EditorTrackingEnabled>
   <CreatorFieldName />
   <CreatedAtFieldName />
   <EditorFieldName />
   <EditedAtFieldName />
   <IsTimeInUTC>false</IsTimeInUTC>
   <ChangeTracked>false</ChangeTracked>
   <FieldFilteringEnabled>false</FieldFilteringEnabled>
   <FilteredFieldNames xsi:type="typens:Names" />
</DETableInfo>
```

[Screenshot from the application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XsZz.png)

---

**Question:**

How can I only return a single value from the the `<FieldInfos...>` array: the value where `FieldName = ACTIVITY`?

Comment: Your second XML does not appear to have any `STRATEGY` values.

Comment: @MT0 Sorry about that. I updated the question. It should have the `STRATEGY` values now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXTRACTVALUE` is deprecated. Use `XMLTABLE` with the XPATH `/DETableInfo/Subtypes/Subtype/FieldInfos/SubtypeFieldInfo[FieldName="ACTIVITY"]` to filter to only get the `ACTIVITY` values and then go back up the hierarchy to get the sub-type code and name:

```sql
SELECT x.*
FROM   /*sde.*/gdb_items_vw i
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         '/DETableInfo/Subtypes/Subtype/FieldInfos/SubtypeFieldInfo[FieldName="ACTIVITY"]'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(i.definition)
         COLUMNS
           SubType_Code NUMBER        PATH './../../SubtypeCode',
           SubType_Name VARCHAR2(255) PATH './../../SubtypeName',
           Field_Name   VARCHAR2(255) PATH './FieldName',
           Domain_Name  VARCHAR2(255) PATH './DomainName'
       ) x
WHERE  i.name = 'INFRASTR.EVENTS_ONLY_1_ARRAY_VALUE'
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | SUBTYPE_CODE | SUBTYPE_NAME | FIELD_NAME | DOMAIN_NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 0 | ACTIVE TRANSPORTATION | ACTIVITY | ACTIVITY_ATN_1 |
> | 1 | GEODETIC CONTROL SURVEY MONUMENT | ACTIVITY | ACTIVITY_GCSM |
> | 2 | MUNICIPAL STRUCTURES (BRIDGES) | ACTIVITY | ACTIVITY_MS |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bfbc0c628e3e6159e952e20d73e6855f)*

Comment: Do you know if there is a benefit to specifying `[FieldName="ACTIVITY"]` in the `CROSS APPLY`? Or would it behave exactly the same as if we put it in the WHERE clause: `WHERE x.subtype_field = 'ACTIVITY'`?

Comment: @User1974 You can do either. I suspect that doing it in the XPATH is more efficient as you can prevent the SQL engine from generating extra rows and then filtering them out, which is what using a `WHERE` would do. However, the SQL engine is a black box and it may be that the two options are implemented equivalently. The best way is to profile both methods and see which is more efficient for your database version, hardware, etc.

Comment: Thanks. For what it's worth, here are the explain plans for the two options: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of2uH.png . I wonder why the cardinality is so high for the XPATH option?

Comment: @User1974 I would not put too much faith in the stats. They are only correct when the SQL engine has the statistics to support them (for [example](/a/66837438/1509264): user-defined functions will have a ridiculously low cost until you have statistics for them). If there are no statistics then they either get ignored or made up and it may be that the SQL engine cannot work out how many rows will be generated from the `XMLTABLE` and is overestimating one and underestimating the other.