# ORA-31011: XML parsing failed invalid character 3 (U+0003)

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

col1 is CLOB datatype contains XML data. Table 1 contains lot of xml data rows.

```
select xml_type(col1) from table1
```

Above query returns list of rows without any issues but when we scroll the rows in SQL developer it is throwing the below error. So we want to know which row in col1 causing this issue.

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19213: error occurred in XML processing at lines 283
LPX-00217: invalid character 3 (U+0003)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find problem XML values by catching XMLTABLE() errors in custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72778525/find-problem-xml-values-by-catching-xmltable-errors-in-custom-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SQL Developer will fetch the first 50 rows. What you see is SQL Developer lazy-loading the rest of the rows and finding a row where there is a syntax error in the XML.

You can use a simplified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72778553/1509264) to find the errors:

```sql
WITH FUNCTION test_xml(v_xml clob) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_type XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
  v_type := XMLTYPE(v_xml);
  return 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  test_xml(string_column) = 0;
```

Or, if you are on an earlier Oracle version that does not support declaring functions in SQL:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION test_xml(v_xml clob) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_type XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
  v_type := XMLTYPE(v_xml);
  return 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  test_xml(string_column) = 0;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=122534632a6121856cfbd936bad91c5e)*

Comment: @user1894029 Fix the bad data (either `UPDATE` or `DELETE` it). One possible solution is [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=69233f3ec28de2dde54ecd3b6d0521f3), but it is your data and you should know what it means and what you need to do to make it from invalid XML to meaningful, well-formed XML.